# Is it possible to export usage data by collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We use Firebase with a firestore database.

I would like to do some data analysis to identify business logic that performs unnecessary read / write operations. Is it possible to export detailed data on read/write operations, or am I limited to what Google give us via `Firestore Usage`.

Ideally, I would like to export detailed usage data for analysis in R / Python.
Is this possible?

Comment: Does this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) answers your query?

Comment: No, unfortunately the basic export functionality only supports the actual data, and a very limited set of metadata.

At the moment, the only option seems to be analysing audit logging data.

Comment: You can use BigQuery for exporting the data from Firestore. You may explore more on this from the [article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Platform does not provide a straight-forward way to analyze read/write operations by documents/collections.

In the end, I solved this problem by exporting the Firebase audit logs to BigQuery, and cleaning the data manually.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit